# Setting Excel Worksheet Background color other than white or black in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to change the worksheet background color.  I've looked at all the themes but none show the worksheet color.  I have used that in previous Excel which is easier on the eyes than the white.  Does Excel 2016 have that option?

Comment: How about adding background color for all cells in Worksheet directly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only add Pictures as a background. According to [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-sheet-background-3577a762-8450-4556-96a2-cc265abc00a8?ocmsassetID=HP010342150&CorrelationId=313359d9-504f-49f0-8642-6fc73578f1f1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> To use a solid color as a sheet background, you can apply cell shading to all cells in the worksheet.